# Fixing a point in a double integral

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am wondering for what types of function $f(s,t)$, the following equality is true:
$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} f(s,t) dt ds=2\int_{0}^{1} \int_{s}^{1} f(s,t) dtds$$
For example, let $f(s,t)=st$, we have $\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} (st) dt ds = \frac{1}{4} $ and $\int_{0}^{1} \int_{t=s}^{1} (st) dt ds=\frac{1}{8}$. The equality holds. For $f(s,t)=t^2s^2$, this also can hold. I think it also holds for $f(s,t)=s^nt^n$ in general

However, consider $f(s,t)=t^2s^3$, one can show that $\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} (s^3t^2) dt ds = \frac{1}{12} $ but $\int_{0}^{1} \int_{t=s}^{1} (s^3t^2) dt ds=\frac{3}{84}$. Does that mean the equality can hold only when $s,t$ have the same power?

If $g(x)$ is some continuous function, does the equality hold for $f(s,t)=g(s)-g(t)$? Thank you for any insight!

Comment: Certainly it holds for all functions $f$ with $f(s,t)=f(t,s)$. (This gives symmetry about the line $s=t$.) Without this symmetry, we can write down functions where it fails, but we can certainly write down functions where it still holds by happenstance. I think you'll have problems with your $f(s,t)=g(s)-g(t)$; won't you always get $0$ for the answer?

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you!